# How to get Ai to turn slower?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, game-physics

Scenario: I want to make objects follow the player with a given speed. I've made the code that makes the objects follow the player (which works). In order to make the object follow the player I checked what side the object is and then depending on that it would calculate the speed in which it would need to affect the x and y values to make it move in that direction.

Problem: If the player was to get around the Ai the Ai would make sharp turns in order to get to the player. What I want is something to make it the turns less sharply and instead make wider turns.

any questions? Please ask!

My code:

```
public void facePlayer(){
    double division = (double)Math.abs(player.getY() - enemyy) / Math.abs(player.getX() - enemyx);
    dir = Math.atan(division);      
    dir = lerp(dir,division,spd);
    if (enemyx >= player.getX() && enemyy <= player.getY()) {
        enemyx -= (spd * Math.cos(dir));
        enemyy += (spd * Math.sin(dir));
    }

    //if Coin is top left
    if (enemyx >= player.getX() && enemyy >= player.getY()) {
        enemyx -= (spd * Math.cos(dir));
        enemyy -= (spd * Math.sin(dir));
    }

    //if Coin is bottom right
    if (enemyx <= player.getX() && enemyy <= player.getY()) {
        enemyx += (spd * Math.cos(dir));
        enemyy += (spd * Math.sin(dir));
    }

    //if Coin is bottom left
    if (enemyx <= player.getX() && enemyy >= player.getY()) {
        enemyx += (spd * Math.cos(dir));
        enemyy -= (spd * Math.sin(dir));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't allow your AI to make 180° turns, remember your last shipDir direction (angle) and allow only 90° turns (+/- 1 to shipDir).

Comment: I will try it but because it is in radians I would probably need to switch back and forth to check if it is 90 or not.

Comment: Well this is what I put and when I tried it it didn't seem to have that much of an affect.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do it is to use [Linear Inerpolition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) Which is great for stuff like this. A simple LERP function would look like this:

```
public double lerp(double x, double y, double speed){
    return (y - x) * speed;
}
```

You could then call this function as:

```
dir = lerp(dir, newDir, .01);
```

And then simply decrease/ increase the speed variable until you get it looking just how you want it.

Linear Interpoliton is also very useful when it comes to networking.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on how I am supposed to use this?

Comment: instead of setting your dir straight away to the angle between the enemy ship and the player, instead make it so that the enemy ships angle is set to the lerp of the angle between them.

dir = lerp(dir, division, .01);

Something along them lines should do the trick, but you may have to call your facePlayer() function more than once.

Comment: Ok so I tried the dir = lerp(dir,division,.01) and it had some interesting effects. What it seems to do is when they need to make a turn they stop and studder a bit and then continue towards the player

Comment: The reason this happens is because you've only called the function once, you've told the game to move a little bit towards the player and then carry on moving, you need to make sure the function is called constantly until the ship is facing the player. you could just simply place the function into the ships tick function or equivalent assuming you have one.

Comment: What do you mean called constantly? the FacePlayer() is basically my move method which is called everytime so it would update the enemy's x and y values. Ill post an edit soon of what it looks like now

Comment: Every time the faceplayer method is called, the enemy ship should rotate towards the player a little bit.

Comment: Well in  theory it should but it is kinda hard to tell for the fact that graphically they are just rectangles (most of them just using fillRect) so they dont actually actually face to where they are supposed to go. What they do is instead to move in the direction they "face".

Answer (score 0):

LERP is one good method.

Another way is taking different point of view. You can add inertia and simple physics. So it cannot change directly its speed, but instead it can only apply force to itself. Think of the player and your object being connected by a spring.

It should naturally make the turns wider, and you will be able to modify it dynamically.

`F = versor * constant` , where versor is pointing from your object to the player.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by agent. Do you mean the object that is following the player?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion.